# I am trying to get NETFLIX , select tag ands sign in button in one line but i am unable to do. I am a beginner and often get stuck in this

Tags: html, css, web, web-development-server

I have tried display :flex; with justify-content: space-between, align-items:center;
Also tried changing width , height, display- inline, inline-block but couldn't figure out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clone@Netflix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="netflix.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <h2>NETFLIX</h2>
            <span class="language">
                <select name="#" id="lang_inner">
                    <option value="en">English</option>
                    <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
                    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
                    <option value="es">Espaniol</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <button class="signin_button">Sign in</button>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you planning to do this navigation bar vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76822731/13273704) work for you? If so, could you please mark it as correct? Or if not, did it accomplish anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `float: left;`:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header{
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

header .navigation * {
    float: left;
}

header .navigation > :not(h2) {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clone@Netflix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="netflix.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <h2>NETFLIX</h2>
            <span class="language">
                <select name="#" id="lang_inner">
                    <option value="en">English</option>
                    <option value="hi">Hindi</option>
                    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
                    <option value="es">Espaniol</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <button class="signin_button">Sign in</button>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` will work, but you need to use it differently.  It only applies to an element's immediate children, not to anything nested more deeply than that, so in your code, the `display: flex` property in the `header` only applies to the `nav` element's layout and not to the `nav`'s children, and those children are the elements you're trying to control.

Instead, you should put it on the `nav` element, like so:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Then adjust `justify-content` if you don't want those three elements spaced miles apart from each other.